# How to perform Download Operation using asp.net core 2.0 Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I'am working on **Document Management System** ,i successfully completed **Uploading** and **Deleting** the file, but I'am unable to to perform  **Download** operation from database,I'am new in Razor Pages,So If anybody help me then it will be great appreciated .bellow are more details about my project.

This is my Index.cshtml

```html
<div>    
    <table class="table " style="background-color:lightskyblue;" >
        <thead style="font-weight:bold ;color:white;background-color:black;margin-right:-50px;padding-right:80px;">
            <tr  style="background-color:darkblue;color:white;">
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Schedule[0].Title)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Schedule[0].UploadDT)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Schedule[0].PublicScheduleSize)
                </th>
                @*<th class="text-center">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Schedule[0].PrivateScheduleSize)
            </th>*@
                <th class="text-center">Operations</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Schedule)
            {
                <tr style="font-weight:bold">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UploadDT)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PublicScheduleSize)
                    </td>
                    
                        <td style="margin-left:-60px;">
                            @*<a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>*@
                            <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" role="button">Delete</a>
                        </td >
                        <td >
                            <a asp-page="./Download" download="item.UploadDT" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt " role="button">Download</a>
                        </td>
                    
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is PageModel(Codebehind)

```csharp
namespace DMS.Pages.Schedules
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly DMS.Models.DatabaseContext _context;

        public IndexModel(DMS.Models.DatabaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public FileUpload FileUpload { get; set; }

        public IList<Schedule> Schedule { get; private set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Schedule = await _context.Schedule.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Schedule = await _context.Schedule.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
                return Page();
            }
            var publicScheduleData = await FileHelpers.ProcessFormFile(FileUpload.UploadPublicSchedule, ModelState);
            FileHelpers.ProcessFormFile(FileUpload.UploadPrivateSchedule, ModelState);

            ProcessFormFile method

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Schedule = await _context.Schedule.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
                return Page();
            }
            var schedule = new Schedule()
            {
                PublicSchedule = publicScheduleData,
                PublicScheduleSize = FileUpload.UploadPublicSchedule.Length,
                 FileUpload.UploadPrivateSchedule.Length,
                Title = FileUpload.Title,
                UploadDT = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
            _context.Schedule.Add(schedule);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you would need to add the path of the file can you specify where is the link to download eg ```<a href="https://www.example.com/CV.pdf" target="_blank" >Download CV</a>```

Comment: I completely don't know how to write code for download operation ,so can u please give me full view of this operation. This is my download `link button` `<a asp-page="./Download" download="item.UploadDT" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt " role="button">Download</a> ` I want to perform download from database

Comment: i have posted the link in answer. please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very difficult to parse, but it seems that ultimately, you're storing the file as a blob in your database table. Generally speaking, you'll need an action that retrieves this data from the database and returns it as a `FileResult`:

```
public OnDownloadGetAsync(int scheduleId)
{
    var schedule = await _context.Set<Schedule>().FindAsync(scheduleId);
    if (schedule == null)
        return NotFound();

    return File(schedule.PublicSchedule, schedule.PublicScheduleType);
}
```

That second parameter to `File` is the mime-type (i.e. `text/csv`, `application/vnd.excel`, `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, etc.). If you know it's always going to be the same type of file, you can hard-code it, but ideally this is something you should also be persisting in your database (which is why I "created" a `PublicScheduleType` property to persist it). You'll obviously need to revise your upload code to persist the content type of the file being uploaded.

Something like an excel spreadsheet should force a download regardless, but the default will be to deliver the file as "inline", or attempt to display it in the browser. If you want to always force a download, you can provide a third param to `File`, with a filename:

```
return File(schedule.PublicSchedule, schedule.PublicScheduleType, "schedule.xlsx");
```

Once you have that set up, then you simply link to this handler:

```
<a asp-page="Index" asp-handler="Download" asp-route-scheduleId="@schedule.Id">Download</a>
```